# De-identified data from BigQuery with DLP

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dlp

I would like to de-identified my PII data that already in BiqQuery with Google DLP, and store the result in another table in BigQuery. Is that possible ? and how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Currently the main recommendation is to use dataflow.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dlp-dataflow-deidentification

Answer (score 1):

The different methods for [De-Indentifying](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/deidentify-sensitive-data#de-identification_transformations) sensitive data in DLP are available through API, for example, we can use `replaceConfig` to replace from:

*My email address is astacko@example.com.*

to

*My email address is [email-address].*

by using an API request like this:

```
"deidentifyConfig":{
    "infoTypeTransformations":{
      "transformations":[
        {
          "infoTypes":[
            {
              "name":"EMAIL_ADDRESS"
            }
          ],
          "primitiveTransformation":{
            "replaceConfig":{
              "newValue":{
                "stringValue":"[email-address]"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

So, for your use case you would need to integrate the De-identifying API into a flow that reads from BigQuery, perform the De-identifying transformations and writes back to BigQuery.

[Cloud DLP in action](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/taking-charge-of-your-data-using-cloud-dlp-to-de-identify-and-obfuscate-sensitive-information) is a Google post that talks about this. It points out to Dataflow to achieve this use case. Please refer to this [Reference Architecture](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dlp-dataflow-deidentification#reference-architecture) to have an idea of how this can work, in there you will find some [Java classes examples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dlp-dataflow-deidentification/tree/master/src/main/java/com/google/swarm/tokenization). You can modify it if needed so that you can ingest it to BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick workaround, I would consider moving the tables with PII into a dataset with restricted access.  Then, in a new dataset, create a view that does not include the sensitive columns.  Give users query access to only the dataset with the view, and not the private dataset.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/share-access-views

Answer (score 0):

This feature is currently in preview (October 2022). Talk to your Google Cloud sales rep to see if it can be enabled for your project.